# In PotPlayer is there a way to move OR copy the current playing file to another directory (besides trash)? Or any way with AutoHotKey or similar?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, video-streaming, media-player

When reviewing multiple video files for Video Editing, and library mgmt, PotPlayer ticks many boxes for fast reviewing, but can't find this.

Thought i'd reach out here for anything I might have missed OR suggestions using autohotkey or any other possible solution.

Keeping it all in PotPlayer would save me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about PotPlayer, there may be a better way to do it completely in the background.  Easy enough to do in AutoHotkey though if you don't mind a few dialogs popping up and disappearing again.

This script opens the FileInfo dialog, copies the filename to clipboard and then does a filecopy of that path to another path.  Changes you will need to make to the script below:

- Remove the `MsgBox` once you've tested that it works to grab the current filename
- The copy destination is hardcoded to `c:\temp` currently → change that to whatever you like
- You can change the shortcut key assigned in the script below if you want (currently `F8`)
- Set the option to overwrite in the filecopy statement if you want that (or not)

This script was tested working down to the message box that displays the current filename that it grabs, so assuming the filecopy will work fine after that--if not it's a starting point for you to play with.

Script Example:

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Return

#IfWinActive, ahk_class PotPlayer
F8::
    SendInput ^{F1}         ; Pull up info dialog
    WinWaitActive, Playback/System Information,,2
    If ErrorLevel {
        Tooltip, Couldn't find dialog... exiting...
        Sleep 2000
        ToolTip
        Return          ; couldn't find dialog
    }

    lastClipboard := ClipboardAll       ; Save existing clipboard contents

    SendInput ^{Tab 2}      ; Focus tab control at top
    Sleep 100
    SendInput {Right}       ; Focus FileInfo tab
    Sleep 100
    SendInput {Space}       ; Select FileInfo
    Sleep 100

    SendInput !c            ; Select copy to clipboard
    Sleep 100
    SendInput {Space}       ; Execute
    Sleep 100

    SendInput !c            ; Select close
    Sleep 100
    SendInput {Space}       ; execute
    Sleep 100

    FileName := ""
    Loop, Parse, % FileInfo:=Clipboard, `n
    {
        If InStr(A_LoopField, "Complete name") {
            FileName := Trim(Substr(A_LoopField, InStr(A_LoopField, ":")+1)) ; get path and file after colon and trim spaces
            Break
        }
    }

    Clipboard := lastClipboard ; restore previous clipboard

    If (FileName = "") {
        Tooltip, Couldn't find filename... exiting...
        Sleep 2000
        ToolTip
        Return
    }

    ; Remove this when no longer needed...
    MsgBox % "Filename Found: " FileName

    ; Put the target directory of choice here instead of c:\temp
    ; add a 1 as the third arg to overwrite if needed
    FileCopy, % FileName, % "C:\temp"     

Return
```

Comment: Awesome work @jjohnston2 thank you! How is this detecting the currently playing file?

Comment: It opens the file info dialog box which you can try normally by pressing Ctrl F1 and then going to the middle tab to get the file info with the full path, which it then copies to the clipboard and parses in order to copy it to another folder

Comment: Im a AHK newbie, so I might be missing it entirely, but couldn't get this to work. I'm using AHK Portable, appears in tray and is running the script I created from the above.
I.e. created Potplay.ahk in the Autohotkey directory, double click it, AHK appears in systray, hovering shows 'Potplay.ahk'.

Comment: So I added #IfWinActive, ahk_class PotPlayer
!F10::
    SendInput ^{F1}         ; Pull up info dialog

Should activate on alt-f10? But nothing happens

Comment: You can remove the `#IfWinActive` statement for testing so the hotkey combination will fire with anything open.  If an `#IfWinActive` statement 'breaks' it then the syntax, class, name, etc. needs to be corrected

Comment: To be clear, this is what you're suggesting with the added Alt hotkey I added? (don't know how to preserve formatting)

`ahk_class PotPlayer  
!F10::  
SendInput ^{F1}         ; Pull up info dialog  
WinWaitActive, Playback/System Information,,2  
    If ErrorLevel {  
        Tooltip, Couldn't find dialog... exiting...  
        Sleep 2000  
        ToolTip  
        Return          ; couldn't find dialog  
    } `

Lost me at 'the syntax, class, name, etc. needs to be corrected', total AHK noob sorry :P (and thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

PotPlayer provides a feature to rename files in the playlist.

Open the playlist (default hotkey: F6), right click the target file, choose "add & edit" -> "rename file...  CTRL+M", or select the file in the list and press CTRL+M. There will be a pop-up window to rename the file, a new folder location could be set in the very same window.

Alternatively, press F6 to open playlist (the UI will automatically get focus in that panel), if playlist is already opened, press F6 twice to re-open it and automatically get focus, then just press CTRL+M.

The procedure above is not easy to prorgam, mainly because the difficulty to determine whether the playlist panel is already opened and thus if need to press F6 twice. But since the key strokes are few, this method is fine to be done by hand.

---

The other method is using a 3rd party program/script to do the rename/move job, and feed it with the file path parsed from the pop-up window called by CTRL+F1 in potplayer. I do have a self-using python, which can auto find the playing potplayer window, and bring it to foreground, send hotkeys to the window, get file info, parse out file path, pop up a pretty GUI dialog for user to rename/move the file.

The code of related classes and functions are separated in several python files in [my github repo](https://github.com/mo-han/mo-han-toolbox#potplayerkit), you could view them online.